# CanCan + Devise: Admin user can't get permission even though he should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

Here are the code.

```rb
class WebsitesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  ...
end
```

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  check_authorization :unless => :do_not_check_authorization?

  private
    def do_not_check_authorization?
      respond_to?(:devise_controller?)
    end
end
```

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role? == "admin"
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? == "developer"
      can :manage, :websites
      can :manage, :pages
      can :manage, :templates
    elsif user.role? == "editor"
      can :manage, :pages
    end
  end
end
```

From the look of it, a user with admin role should be able to do anything with Website controller because of `can :manage, :all`.

But when I hit websites/index, I get

```
CanCan::AccessDenied in WebsitesController#index

You are not authorized to access this page.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: hi! are you using something like `rolify` to manage the roles of your users?

Comment: @jvnill, I solved my problem. It see my stupid mistake in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm so dumb.

I `user.role?` returns `true` but `true == "admin"` is always false.

Comment: yep that's what I thought so too (not the dumb part :p). I thought you're probably looking at something like `user.role?('admin')` rather than the code in your question :)